# sed replacing content with star

Tags: sed, tcsh

I can use sed from tcsh like this:

```
set a = `echo $a | sed -e 's_old_new_'`
```

Everything is fine, but when I want to do this:

```
set a = `echo $a | sed -e 's_old_*new_'`
```

I can see "set: No match." . How I can escape this star?

Comment: What is exactly that you are trying to do and what is the example content of $a initially?

Comment: Exactly I want to convert given number to number that I can use in bc. Example content of $a : 2, 2.0, 2., .2, -2e2, +2e+2 etc. My sed look like: set a = `echo $a | sed -e 's_[DdEeQ][+-]\?_*10^_'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about tcsh but few experiments suggest the set assigning a variable attempts to expand right side *. Here is something that may help:

```
set a="`echo '2e2' | sed -e 's_e_*_'`"
echo "$a"
2*2
echo $a
echo: No match.
```

So double quote around back quotes and it will work.

```
set a = "`echo $a | sed -e 's_old_new_'`"
```

Answer (score 0):

A command substitution (`` ` `` or `$(..)`) that is not enclosed in double quotes is subject to filename expansion (aka 'globbing') and word splitting.

Normally, a variable assignment would suppress filename expansion and word splitting of the RHS (even without double quotes), but apparently not filename expansion in the case of command substitution.

Here's a test I ran for reference purposes:

```
$ touch randomfile
$ a="*file"
$ var_expand=$a
$ echo "$var_expand"
*file
$
$ cmd_subst=$(echo '*file')
$ echo "$cmd_subst"
randomfile
```

So I guess it's good practice to always double quote the command substitution when you are assigning to variable.

```
safe="$(cmd)"
```

Note: This is tested in Bash but I think tcsh exhibits a similar behavior in this respect.